# how to send the data in Json structure

Tags: json, rest, dojo

I have a rest service for which I am sending the Json data as `["1","2","3"]`(list of strings) which is working fine in firefox rest client plugin, but while sending the data in application the structure is `{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3"}` format, and I am not able to pass the data, how to convert the `{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3"}` to `["1","2","3"]` so that I can send the data through application, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see :http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/json.html

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the json is `{ "index" : "value" }`, is what I'm seeing in `{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3"}`, then we can take advantage of that information and you can do this:

```
var myObj = {"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3"};
var convertToList = function(object) {
   var i = 0;
   var list = [];
   while(object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {   // check if value exists for index i
        list.push(object[i]);          // add value into list
        i++;                           // increment index
   } 
   return list;
};

var result = convertToList(myObj);    // result: ["1", "2", "3"]
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/NzudC/

Use a fake index to "*iterate*" through the list. Keep in mind that this won't work if there is a break in the indices, can't be this: `{"0":"1","2":"3"}`

Comment: @user1490244 Can you post your code and/or provide more information as to why it's not working still? maybe any errors being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse out the json back into a javascript object. There are parsing tools in the later iterations of dojo as one of the other contributors already pointed out, however most browsers support `JSON.parse()`, which is defined in ECMA-262 5th Edition (the specification that JS is based on). Its usage is:

```
var str = your_incoming_json_string,
// here is the line ...
obj = JSON.parse(string);

// DEBUG: pump it out to console to see what it looks like
a.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
});
```

For the browsers that don't support `JSON.parse()` you can implement it using json2.js, but since you are actually using dojo, then `dojo.fromJson()` is your way to go. Dojo takes care of browser independence for you.

```
var str = your_incoming_json_string,
// here is the line ...
obj = dojo.fromJson(str);

// DEBUG: pump it out to console to see what it looks like
a.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
});
```

If you're using an AMD version of Dojo then you will need to go back to the Dojo documentation and look at dojo/_base/json examples on the [dojo.fromJson](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/fromJson.html) page.